# Is it possible to get location using Earth’s magnetic field (Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)

Tags: android, geolocation, android-wifi

I'm trying to do a Indoor Positioning Systems (IPS). so GPS will not the best way to do this. my question is,  s it possible to get location using Earth’s magnetic field (Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) ? why I come up like because of this [article](http://www.livescience.com/49468-turtles-migration-magnetic-field.html)

Hope you guys will help me out... or if you guys have a good idea better than this please comment.... have a nice day....

Comment: I hope you know the difference between compass and map.

Comment: Did you read that article??? if Sea Turtles Use Earth's Magnetic Field to Find Home then why cant we use it?

Comment: They dont get latitude or longitude, they get the directions. they travel either east, west, north or south. Just because you are curious, read articles on migration of birds too.

Comment: you guys have any suggestions ?

Comment: GPS with less accuracy using wifi or mobile data. I don't think you can have anything better currently.

Answer (score 2):

GPS will give you coordinates,

Magnetic field will give BEARING.... It will not give the coordinate information.

The example of turtles that you gave are not concerned with their coordinates.... They use the magnetic field to know which direction they are heading in

If GPS is very slow/innacurate for you, Try using FusedLocation API,

It will use GPS, Network (signal triangulation), proximity and the magnetic sensors to provide an accurate Location and Bearing faster than just using a GPS...

NOTE: For it to work fast, the Data/wifi has to be on... else it will use just GPS if you requested a FINE Location and it will again be very slow indoors

Options for accuracy/power in fused provider

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest

FusedLocationProvider details:

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi